# PHP String replace in LARGE CSV not functioning

Tags: php

I am trying to find the string Villege\ in a large CSV and replace it with just Villege.

I have written the below code but it is not replacing the String at all.

```
$sourcePath = 'EstablishmentExport.csv';
$targetPath = 'EstablishmentExporttarget.csv';
$source = fopen($sourcePath, 'r');
$target = fopen($targetPath, 'w');

while(! feof($source))
  {
  $line = str_replace("Villege\\","Villege",fgets($source));
  fwrite($target, $line);
  }

fclose($source);
fclose($target);
```

I have even tested this by creating a text file with Villege\ and it did not replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the quotes like this:

```
$line = str_replace('Villege\\', 'Villege', fgets($source));
```

Comment: Awesome that works, but why did double quatation not work? Also what would I put as a parameter if I want to replace `\"` with just `"`.

Comment: To be honest, I just tried it. I don't have a detailed explanation for it. ;) If it helped you, I would appreciate it if you marked my answer as the one that solved your problem.

Comment: To answer your second problem - this worked for me: `$line = str_replace('Villege\"', 'Villege"', fgets($source));`

Comment: sorry I might of been a bit unclear. I just want to replace all the `\"` with just `"`. But it isnt working. I tried this but no luck `$line = str_replace('\\"', '"', fgets($source));`

Comment: sorry I might of been a bit unclear. I just want to replace all the `\"` with just `"`. But it isnt working. I tried this but no luck `$line = str_replace('\\"', '"', fgets($source));`. It works the text file just has the string I want to replace by itself. But in my CSV its like this `,"No. 1-16, Damei Road, Checheng Villege\",`